# Div appearing in center breaks if user has scrolled

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, css-position

I have the body/html of my page set up like this with CSS:

```
body, html {
    height: 100%;
    margin: 0px;
    padding: 0px;
    font-family: Segoe, Segoe UI, DejaVu Sans, Trebuchet MS, Verdana, " sans-serif";
    font-size: 14px;
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    background: #282828;
    min-width: 100%;
    min-height: 100%;
}
```

I then have a popup that I occasionally append to the page (body) using JQuery. This popup is DIV as follows:

```
.error_popup_container {
    width: 400px;
    height: auto;
    padding: 10px;
    background: #454545;
    border: solid #fafafa 2px;
    border-radius: 1px;
    z-index: 3;
    position: absolute;
    -webkit-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    -moz-box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    box-shadow: 0px 0px 5px 0px rgba(0,0,0,0.75);
    left: 50%;
    top: 50%;
    margin: -50px 0 0 -200px; /* 50px = half of height, 140px = half of width */
}
```

The issue is that the div only appears in the middle of the page if the user hasn't scrolled.

If the user has scrolled the div will be out of view.

I need the div to appear in the middle of the page no matter how far they have scrolled. Any ideas?

I've played around a ton but haven't found the cause. I'm sure it's something simple.

Comment: Please add your html to go with your style

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Agree with the position: fixed; and to keep it centered, I would use:

```
/*modal-wrapper*/ {
    position: fixed;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%,-50%);
}
```

If the modal will ever be longer than a small viewport, you could add a media query breakpoint with an overflow-y: scroll; property.

Comment: Thanks Ryan, I knew it'd be something painfully obvious!

Answer (score 0):

I think you probably just want to use `position: fixed`